# SQLite ORDER: Distribute result around center

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Is it possible to order a SQLite select result in way that highest value is in the center and lower value are distributed around center till start and end of result set?

data set:

```
5 
3 
2 
1 
1 
1 
1
```

desired result:

```
1 
1 
3 
5 
2 
1 
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign a row number to each value and with `MAX()` window function get the difference of each value from the max value of the table so they can be distributed around the max value:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) % 2 = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * 
         (MAX(col) OVER () - col)
```

Change `col` to the column's name.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5180fe85872db93d49898ee9006e7724).